# Java package naming convention in worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, java-package

I am facing new problem in worklight that, when I am giving package name like bha.testing. The adapter is giving error that bha is not defined and throws error.

If I will give name like com.testing and change my adapter accordingly and run it, It will running fine.

So, I have question that it is compulsory in worklight to give package name that is starts with com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use either com, net or org for package names.

This is due to a limitation in the Rhino engine version used within Worklight.

Comment: This is correct. Package name should start with com/net/org.